# Uv stretching along tris?

Tags: materials, uv

I'm cheating my way out of making angled stacked header bricks above a portal by simply scaling one side of my uv plane. However, instead of stretching like expected for some reason the texture just switches direction along what seems to be a diagonal of the plane (or, the edge of where the tri would be). Does anyone have any idea what causes this or how it can be fixed? Thanks!

To be clear, this is the pattern I want:
[image]

The file can be found here (it's a work file so I can only upload the relevant bit. However, the problem persists): https://pasteall.org/blend/f0f4038816b14727af3d99d02519d434

(yes, scale and rotation are applied)

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?so I can take a look at it

Comment: @Ribbit12 I edited the post with the link (https://pasteall.org/blend/f0f4038816b14727af3d99d02519d434)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you create unstable UV geometry when you stretch the face this way. The calculation happens from the vertices. And you just have four.

That you can see one half nearly working but the other half not is because a quad face is made by two underlying tris. And each underlying tri is separately calculated. And the result is then distorted as you can see it.

One solution would be to subdivide the face, so that you have enough vertices to calculate the UV in a proper way. I get a somehow useful result after 3 subdivisions.

The better solution would be to modify the texture instead of distorting the UV. Distorted UV is always unstable UV.

[image]

Comment: So just a technical limitation then. Anyway, subdividing it does indeed fix my problem so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!